# Manipulate PDF using Java

Tags: java, pdf

I wanted to ask how can we proceed about manipulating a PDF file using Java. I am familiar with the structure of a PDF file (how its objects are arranged etc.). I would like to know how to proceed from scratch. By scratch I mean I don't want to use the freely available API's and libraries available, I want to strip a PDF down to its constituent objects.

Comment: That's a huge question, structured documents, parsing, DOMs, can't tell where to start. Have a look at some of the open source implementations, e.g. iText see what you need to start brushing up on maybe.

Answer (score 3):

Don;t try to reinvent the wheel.
There is already excellent work done [here](http://itextpdf.com/)

Comment: Is it a hell of a lot of work? It is not my intention to move earth and stars to do it by myself. If it is so, I can use iText too. Also, if it is a lot of work in Java, can this be done easily in any other High Level Language - Python, for instance?

Comment: Yes, it's a lot of work, regardless of language.  C# has iText.NET.

Comment: There are also a huge amount of inconsistencies and bugs in lots of PDF files and IText have already spent years on tuning the code for these cases.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I am better off using the iText libraries than meddling myself.

Comment: As Mark said...there are years of development done, so you can trust them :)